# JMeter XPath Extractor on HTML5 content

Tags: html, xpath, jmeter

I'm trying to get JMeter to read a pre-filled form input value at the following XPath: `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[1]/input/@value`

Since I only got ERROR as a result, I investigated and enabled Tidy (tolerant parser) as well as verbosity (not Quiet; Report errors) and I found this:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: TidyException: line 65 column 9 - Error: <nav> is not recognized!
line 95 column 11 - Error: <nav> is not recognized!
InputStream: Doctype given is ""
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 4.01 Transitional
85 warnings, 2 errors were found!
This document has errors that must be fixed before
using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.
```

Since we are in 2017, the document is of course written in HTML5 and `<nav>` is a perfectly valid tag. Yet Tidy fails to recognize it. I'm running an up-to-date Arch Linux system with JMeter 3.1 r1770033.

How can I use XPath in JMeter for HTML5 websites?

Comment: Show `HTML` for target `input` field

Comment: `<input id="title_de" class="string optional" value="Well this is a mighty value." name="my_element[title_de]" type="text">`

Comment: Did you try to use https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5 instead of current `Tidy` version?

Comment: I've seen that it exists, but I don't know how to integrate it into JMeter. An answer explaining how to make tidy-html5 run in JMeter might actually be a valid anser to this question.

Comment: why don't use Regular Expression Extractoror Post Processor JMeter?

Comment: Thanks, Regex is the workaround needed here.

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Xpath Extractor`:

```
//input[@id='title_de']/@value
```

screenshot references:
Xpath Extractor configuration:
[image]

View Results Tree:
[image]

---

Using `Regular Expression Extractor`:

```
input id="title_de" class="string optional" value="(.*?)"
```

Screenshot references:
[image]

View Results Tree (highlighted the captured value):
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Regular Expression Extractor is a working alternative. The XPath Extractor will not work because there's a `<nav>` elsewhere in the document, but Regexes are not concerned by this.

Comment: One more thing: If the field names contains symbols like `[`, those must be escaped for the regex to work: `\[`

Comment: Yes. `[]` is used for `character classes`. so escape using `\`. complete list is here http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html